# Vue.js 2.0 start component from start

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

With `vue.js 1.0` I started my router like this:

```
router.start(App, 'app');
```

But this does not work anymore with `vue.js 2.0`. According to the documentation I've to do it like this now:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('app');
```

Is it possible to do it the old way? Because now I've to do this in my `laravel blade` file:

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view
            transition
            transition-mode="out-in">
    </router-view>
</div>
```

But I would like to do that ^ within a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap an element in your component with `transition`

Sample from docs

```
<template>
  <div id="demo">
    <button v-on:click="show = !show">
      Toggle
    </button>
    <transition name="fade">
      <p v-if="show">hello</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
      show: true
    }
  })
</script>

<style>
  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0
  }
</style>
```

Docs: [vuejs transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components)

Comment: This is not what I mean